# Send JSON with image as bytes using WebSocket

Tags: python, opencv, web, websocket, base64

I want to send and receive image from cv2.Videocapture using WebSocket.

It could get json, but it couldn't decoded.

We need result that can be opened using cv2.imshow().

Somebody help me...

**This is Client**

```
ret, image_np = cap.read()
        IMAGE_SHAPE = image_np.shape
        encoded_image = base64.b64encode(image_np)
        print(type(encoded_image))
        payload = {
            'from': 'rasp',
            'image': str(encoded_image),
            'shape': IMAGE_SHAPE,
        }

        data = json.dumps(payload)

        try:
            # Send encoded image data.
            await websocket.send(data)

            # receive server message
            received_data = await websocket.recv()
            print('< {}'.format(received_data))

            # image = base64.b64decode(received_data)
            # np_image = np.fromstring(image, dtype=np.uint8)
            # source = np_image.reshape(IMAGE_SHAPE)
            return websocket
        except Exception:
            print('WebSocket send or receive error.')
            exit(1)
```

**This is Server**

```
async def server_on(websocket, path):
payload = {
    'from': 'image-server',
    # 'result': {
    #     # Default is null.
    #     'isPerson': <bool>,
    #     'centerPoint': <(x, y)>,
    # },
}

data = json.dumps(payload)

try:
    payload = await websocket.recv()
    receive_data = json.loads(payload)
    # At this line doesnt work... 
    decoded_image = base64.b64decode(receive_data['image'])
    image_np = np.fromstring(decoded_image, dtype=np.uint8)
    source = image_np.reshape(receive_data['shape'])


    await websocket.send(data)
except Exception:
    websocket.close()
    return
```

Comment: Is the payload encoded exactly the same as the one received?

Comment: I found that str(encoded_image) increase 3bytes compared with encoded_image. But, i don't know how to correctly change bytes to string to send with JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **Client** I would say that you have an extra operation not needed.
Based on your latest comment, you might not need to use: `str(encoded_image)`.

You could try to use: `base64.encodestring(image_np)` that will send you back a string container.

```
ret, image_np = cap.read()
        IMAGE_SHAPE = image_np.shape
        encoded_image = base64.encodestring(image_np)
        print(type(encoded_image))
        payload = {
            'from': 'rasp',
            'image': encoded_image.decode('utf-8'),
            'shape': IMAGE_SHAPE,
        }
```

Comment: I'm really really sorry. Too late. I did that but had log: 'TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable'.. Maybe because it is bytes. I'm trying to fixing it about .... 1 and half weeks

Comment: I understand it better. You have bytes and not string. Can you try to use base64.encodestring()?

Comment: It doesn't work too. Exactly what i want to know is that why it increase 3byte .. bytes -> string. I think there is answer.. I'm very appreciate for your help

Comment: Fix it! Thank for your help Like this way,                                                                       encoded_image = base64.b64encode(image_np)


            payload = {
                'from': 'rasp',
                'image': encoded_image.decode('utf-8'),
                'shape': IMAGE_SHAPE,
            }