# Python Websocket Broken Pipe Error while sending picture within JSON

Tags: python, json, websocket

I am trying to send a JSON that includes encoded image that acquired from openCV `cv2.videoCapture()` to websocket.

At first I did it with only `base64.b64encode()` and i got "Not JSON serializable" error.

and then i found [the correct way to send an image over json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50266553/send-json-with-image-as-bytes-using-websocket)

But then when i try to do it i got "Broken pipe error"

Here is my code on the client side:

```
encoded_img = base64.b64encode(gbr)
new_json = {'probability':json_return['probability'],'name':json_return['name'],'image':encoded_img.decode('utf8')}
payload = json.dumps(new_json)
ws.send(payload)
```

Server Side:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
async def hello(websocket, path):
   name = await websocket.recv()
   print('Received', name)
   await websocket.send(name)
   print('sent back to client')
start_server = websockets.serve(hello, '0.0.0.0', 5051)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

> BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Could you guys please help me with this?

Comment: Any update on this one? I probably have the same issue!